# Can I exclude files like I do folders in the config for sublime?

Tags: json, sublimetext3

Is it possible for sublime not to display files such as `package-lock.json` the same way you can tell it not to display folder such as node_modules using:

```
  "folder_exclude_patterns":
  [
    "node_modules",
    ".git"
  ],
```

I'm referring to the sidebar display of files and folders.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you use the `file_exclude_patterns` setting for that. The default uses wildcards:

```
    "file_exclude_patterns": ["*.pyc", "*.pyo", "*.exe", "*.dll", "*.obj","*.o", "*.a", "*.lib", "*.so", "*.dylib", "*.ncb", "*.sdf", "*.suo", "*.pdb", "*.idb", ".DS_Store", "*.class", "*.psd", "*.db", "*.sublime-workspace"],
```

However you can include direct filenames in there to exclude specific files if you want to. Remember that if you want to modify the setting you should copy the entire value from the defaults into your user settings and modify it there; otherwise the default settings will be lost and you'll end up with more files in your sidebar and not less.

Both `file_exclude_patterns` and `folder_exclude_patterns` can be used in your [`sublime-project`](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/projects.html) file if you want certain files and folders to only be excluded for a particular project.

Comment: Nice!.  I am surprised I did not have this property in my user config file already and had to create it myself.